# crop_x value of my avatar not being updated in model which I am saving by paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, jcrop

I am saving my avatar via paperclip after cropping my image via JCrop. The parameters `crop_x`, `crop_y`, `crop_w`, `crop_h` has is coming properly but on doing :

```
status = @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

the crop values are not getting updated. The values are still remaining nil.

I have `:after_update`

```
if avatar_processed.blank?
  self.avatar_processed = true
  avatar.reprocess!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your User model you should have :

```
attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
```

Secondly, if you're using a recent version of Paperclip, calling "avatar.reprocess!" in a "after_update" can create an infinite loop. You should use instead something like this:

```
if avatar_processed.blank?
  self.avatar_processed = true
  avatar.assign(avatar)
  avatar.save
end
```

Hope it will help.